# Best way to read a csv and randomly print a row and column in Python?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.5

I'm trying to create a terms and definition program. I have a csv where I have two columns, terms and definitions. I'm trying to read the file and then randomly select a row in the csv and print the definition and then require an input response to guess the term.

So far I've figured out how to read the file, however I'm stuck on how to randomly select a row and then ask column2 of that row and then wait and check the response with column 1.

So far what I have is:

```
re = open('Psycstudy.csv') 
spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(re)
```

This puts it into a dictionary, but now I'm not sure how to randomly select the definition and term. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module to select a random row.

Given a file `definitions.csv`

```
term1,def1
term2,def2
term3,def3
term4,def4
term5,def5
```

Use the following code to get what you want.

```
import csv
import random

data = [r for r in csv.reader(open('definitions.csv'))]
test = random.choice(data)

print(test)
# ['term3', 'def3']
```

With that, you can use `test[0]` and `test[1]` to get the term and definition. If you want to use a dictionary to do it, you can use a dictionary comprehension instead.

```
data = {r[0]: r[1] for r in csv.reader(open('definitions.csv'))}
term = random.choice(list(data.keys()))

print(term, data[term])
# term2 def2
```

Or if you really want to use the `csv.DictReader()` function, you can use that as well provided you have headers in your file. I added the headers for this last example.

```
data = csv.DictReader(open('definitions.csv'))
term = random.choice([i for i in data])

print(term)
# {'term': 'term1', ' definition': 'def1'}
```

Being curious, I decided to time how long it took with 5,000 definitions. If you have a lot of terms, I'd consider using the comprehension route.

```
List Comprehension: 100 loops, best of 3:  3.08 ms per loop
Dict Comprehension: 100 loops, best of 3:  3.60 ms per loop
Dict Reader:        100 loops, best of 3: 13.50 ms per loop
```

Comment: This won't keep the data in the dictionary form though, which I believe is what the OP is after.